# What fantasy book series has spells cast by two races using dance-like movements, and many worlds?

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for the title of a fantasy series I once started reading at a friend’s house a long time ago, and never got the chance to get the name of the author/series.

It involves the main characters going to multiple worlds; I believe the story opens up on a world ruled by elves and the humans are commoners, slaves, or working class. Also, this world has a series of floating islands that can only be accessed by floating ships, which only the elves have access to.

Another thing I remember is that the series had a unique take on magic, which was done by chanting mysterious words, while using/moving the body in complex movements, almost like a dance. There were two "races" of magic users: one race had mostly-white hair with dark tips, while the other race had mostly-dark hair with white tips.

One of the main characters is one of these races (I can't recall the names of the races, but I know one started with an "A" and the other with a "P"), and I believe (if memory serves right) he is the last of his race, and his name was something like Alfred, Albert, or Alabert. One of his character traits was that he was very clumsy, which made it hard for him to cast spells, but when he did pull one off they were immensely powerful spells.

I also remember there being many worlds that the group of main characters travel to, one being a sort of jungle world with ancient ruins, and a race of huge golems, created by "Alfred's" race long ago by using magic. Another world had huge winged beasts that end up attacking the group of main protagonist, and Alfred ends up casting a very powerful spell, turning himself into a huge dragon, and saving the day.

I know it isn't a lot to go on, but I hope that someone can help me, because I have been searching a long time for this series. I really do want to finish it, I remember it being one of those series that gets you all excited and you can't stop reading. Sorry for the long description. Please, any help is better than none. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: 1) please edit your post to have breaks in the wall of text to improve readablity. 2) please use tag "story-identification" :) see [help] and [tour]

Comment: @RedCaio Or perhaps you could have done it yourself? You can edit any post, use your privileges.

Comment: @Aegon if we always do it for them and never leave helpful tips, then users can't learn, can they. :)

Answer (score 53):

I would assume you are talking about the ["The Death Gate Cycle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_Gate_Cycle) by by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman. The description you give matches the first books pretty well.

---

> One of the main things I remember is the series unique take on magic, which was done by chanting mysterious words, while using/moving the body in complex movements, almost like a dance. There were two "races" of magic users...one race had all white hair with dark tips at the ends of the hair, while the other race had all dark hair with white tips at the ends

The two races you remember match the description of the [Sartan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_Gate_Cycle#Sartan)  and the [Patryns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_Gate_Cycle#Patryns): both use a rune based form of magic, and while the latter utilize a more visual approach (they also have runes "painted" on their bodies) the former do indeed incorporate a form of singing/dancing in their spell.

---

> One of the main characters is one of these races(I can't recall the names of the races, but I know one started with an "A" and the other with a "P") ,and I believe(if memory serves right) he is the last of his race, and his name was something like Alfred, Albert, or alabert.. One of his character traits was that he was very clumsy, which made it hard for him to cast spells, but when he did pull one off....they were immensely powerful spells

You also remember correctly the name of one of the two main characters - he is called Alfred and he is one of the last Sartan, with the other one begin Haplo, a Patryns.

---

> [cut] opens up on a world ruled by elves and the humans are commoners, slaves, or working class. Also, this world has a series of floating islands that can only be accessed by floating ships, which only the elves have access to.

This fits the first book of the series, [Dragon Wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Wing). In this book Haplo is visiting Arianus, the world of Air, which is made up of floating islands as you describe. Also matching is the fact that the island are undergoing a sort of "warfare" with humans and elves fighting for resources and social status where the dwarves, living on the lowest islands, are commonly regarded as "lower level citizen" too.

---

> Another world had huge winged beasts that end up attacking the group of main protaganist, and Alfred ends up casting a very powerful spell, turning himself into a huge dragon, and saving the day

I think you may refer to some event from [Elven Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elven_Star), the second book, but I won't go in further details to avoid spoilers.

---

As a final notice, a little warning if you are planning on buying the books online to complete your collection. 
As far as I know, the titles of the last two books in the series have been switched in some of the first releases of the series in the European area, so ensure you end up with the right books by looking at the description. Last thing you want is risking buying the same book with different covers two times...

Comment: After the first paragraph of description I thought the same. Most definately the deathgate series :-)

Comment: `the dwarves, living on the lowest islands, are commonly regarded as "lower level citizen" too` - with a solid description in the books:  The Elvish word for them is slang for "insect"

Comment: The turn-into-dragon part isn't _Elven Star_, it happens the first time in _Serpent Mage_

Comment: Definitely DGC... my favorite little heptalogy! Imagine my surprise at seeing this on the HNQ list! A lot of influences and mirrorings from the Dragonlance series, for sure... almost a parallel universe.

Comment: You guys are so freaking awesome! I love you all, thank you so very much! I have been dying to finish this series.

Comment: @Izkata - I know, but since the asker stated he was never able to read all the books, I assumed he was talking of that event near the end of the second book instead. That said, it is indeed strange for him to refer to Alfred as the dragon if he read only the first few books :P

Comment: @TylerH As Hickman himself once said "[cut] Fizban is a crazed wizard owned by TSR under copyright, while Zifnab is a completely different crazed wizard owned by Margaret and I. Incidentally, neither Fizban nor Zifnab have any relationship whatsoever to Zanfib—a crazed wizard from our Starshield series. I hope I have cleared this up once and for all.". And *"obviously"* the fact that Fizban owns a book titled "Haplo" means absolutely nothing, so I don't see why you would think that :P

Comment: @SPArchaeologist In which Dragonlance book does it mention Fizban owning a book titled Haplo? I've only read ~ 60-70 of them, I know there's at least a hundred more.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Most likely parts got mixed together due to some similarities, I'm thinking.  The first third of the quote only matches _Elven Star_, the middle matches both _Elven Star_ and _Serpent Mage_, and the last matches _Serpent Mage_ and _Into the Labyrinth_

Comment: @TylerH will have to check, but I seem to remember it was one of the first ones. As far as my memory goes, he doesn't mention it directly either - instead I think that it was Tasslehoff that noticed the book/diary? (and maybe magically "acquires it") among some other Fizban's belonging

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Ah, I would not be surprised if Tasslehoff somehow "found" a book of Fizban's on the ground. He's so thoughtful, that Tas, not wanting anyone to lose their belongings! I wonder if Zifnab has a book titled "Raistlin"...

Comment: @Drumminjay - if this is correct, could you please click on the gray checkmark below the vote buttons on the top left of this answer to mark it as solved? Thanks!